# Load Recaptcha after everything else finished loading

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

The default way of using Recaptcha is putting:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=publickey"></script>
```

where you want the Recaptcha to appear. However, I want it to appear in the middle of the page, but I do not want it to block the rest of the page.

How can I load Recaptcha last?

I have jQuery loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this code it's in JQuery. When document is ready then that means the page is fully loaded.

```
// WHEN THE DOM HAS LOADED FIRE THE reCapInsert FUNCTION TO INSERT THE reCAPTCHA
$( document ).ready(function(){
    reCapInsert();
});

// WHEN CALLED THIS INSERTS THE reCAPTCHA INTO THE PAGE
function reCapInsert(){
    Recaptcha.create('YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE',  // public key
    'recap',
        {
            theme: 'clean',
            callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
        }
);
}
```

All you really do in your HTML page place this code and it will generate a ReCaptcha in that location. (Don't forget to include the recaptcha javascript in the headers of the page.)

```
   <!-- The reCAPTCHA wrapper is here - this is required!! -->
    <div id="recap"></div>
```

Found this example of Non-Ajax version getting loaded by `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var json = {
        type: "text/javascript",
        scriptSrc: "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcXq-oSAAAAAOgwSIew_xq6xkv1QUxrZbRcMz6n",
        id: "theFrame",
        iframeSrc: 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LcXq-oSAAAAAOgwSIew_xq6xkv1QUxrZbRcMz6n'
    };

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = json.type;
    script.src = json.scriptSrc;

    $('<iframe>', {
       src: json.iframeSrc,
       id:  json.id,
       frameborder: 0,
        height: 300,
        width: 500
       }).appendTo('#recap');
});
```

JSFiddle: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vT3Ug/1/)

For more information check out the original source: [Mixing jQuery and reCaptcha](http://rickluna.com/wp/2013/10/mixing-jquery-and-recaptcha-in-forms/)

Comment: This is using the AJAX version of ReCaptcha, I'm using the "normal" version.

Comment: Normal version is iframe right? then add css too it like `display:none;` then no one will see it, give it a id or class use the show() command in `$(document).ready(function() { $("#recap").show(); });`

Comment: Found a solution injecting script when page finishes loading.. it will start loading ReCaptcha after page is loaded, test it out on Chrome Browser Incognito window mode `Ctrl+Shift+N` so it doesn't cache the page.